# Why do I get this error when following the Angular AD official guide?

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I have been following this guide step by step:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp

I inserted the correct Tenant name and application ID in the 2 places I was asked to do so. I sign in successfully to the application but when I press the ToDoList button I get the following error from the server:

[image]

Why is this happening if all the info inserted is correct?

EDIT:

Adding the stacktrace:

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could you check the stacktrace in the inner exception?

Comment: Yes, edited the original message

Comment: Seems like something is going wrong when it is trying to fetch the metadata document from AAD. Are you sure the tenant is correct?

Comment: Yes, the UI shows that the user is signed in